# How To Output CSV File Using QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I was Output CSV File but it is comming blank. I am using template. Do any have good idea for outputing csv for queryset

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader

def GenerateCSV(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'


    t = loader.get_template('company/company_csv.txt')
    data = {
            'companies':Company.objects.exclude(id=1).exclude(
                        company_is_deleted=True
                        ).annotate(
                        number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile')
                        )           
        }
    response.write(t.render(data))
    return response
```

file.txt

```
Sr. No, Company Name, Company Email, Count Of Total Users, Created Date, Current Monthly Payment, Is TABopts Customer, Status
{% for row in data %}"
{{ row.0|addslashes }}", "{{ row.1|addslashes }}", "{{ row.2|addslashes }}", "{{ row.3|addslashes }}", "{{ row.4|addslashes }}"
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you using a template here? Why not use the `csv` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found new approach to do it.

```
# Outputting  CSV
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def GenerateCSV(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Company_Report.csv"'

    query_set = Company.objects.exclude(id=1).exclude(
                            company_is_deleted=True
                            ).annotate(
                            number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile')
                        ) 

    output = []

    for query in query_set:
        output.append([
            query.company_name, 
            query.company_email, 
            query.number_of_company_users, 
            query.company_created, 
            query.company_monthly_payment, 
            query.company_tab_opts, 
            query.company_status, 
            ])

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Company Name', 'Company Email', 'Count Of Total Users', 'Created Date', 'Current Monthly Payment', 'Is TABopts Customer', 'Status'])
    #CSV Data
    writer.writerows(output)

    return response
```